# Entity Framework 5 complex type mapping different representation of the data

Tags: json, entity-framework, dynamic, complextype

If I want to represent different appearances of data, for example, I want to store something in the database as string, however, it's a special type of string, for example, let's say it's a json string. My application is well aware of this type and knows how to deal with it (as a dynamic object in this case). How would I go about representing it as a dynamic object in my application but store it as string in the database, without having to manually serialize and deserialize the json on save and retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually serialize and deserialize your type to string because that is what EF demands. You want to save something as a string = you must have persisted class with filled string property. EF is not able to do that for you.